# Erro de keys Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, mobile, vue.js, pwa

Estou fazendo um PWA utilizando Vue e Quasar, porém quando vou efetuar uma requisição no Postman para aparecer uma notificação push tenho o seguinte retorno no Postman:

```
{
    "multicast_id": idMulticast, //removido por mim ao postar aqui
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "NotRegistered"
        }
    ]
}
```

Já pesquisei um monte sobre esse erro e o mais perto que cheguei da solução foi na pergunta desse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47394909/fcm-error-device-token-not-registered-unregistered), porém já gerei novamente as keys dezenas de vezes e não teve jeito de funcionar, sempre retornando o mesmo erro no Postman.

Estou seguindo todos os passos corretamente, e [aqui](https://github.com/schoolofnetcom/vue-pwa) está o codigo-fonte que tenho como base para o meu PWA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu erro encontra-se documentado [aqui](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref?hl=pt-br#error-codes):

> Um token de registro atual pode deixar de ser válido em diversas
>   situações, como:
>
> - Se o app cliente cancelou o registro com o FCM.
> - Se o app cliente tiver o registro cancelado automaticamente, algo que pode ocorrer se o usuário desinstalar o app. Por exemplo, no iOS,
>     se o serviço de feedback de APNs informou o token delas como inválido.
> - Se o token de registro expirar, por exemplo, se o Google atualizar os tokens de registro, ou o token de APNs expirou para dispositivos
>     iOS.
> - Se o app cliente estiver atualizado, mas a nova versão não estiver configurada para receber mensagens.
>
> Para todos esses casos, remova o token de registro do servidor de app
>   e pare de utilizá-lo para enviar mensagens.

Como diz o último parágrafo, o melhor a fazer é actualizar o token. Vejo que no seu caso este token é obtido no ficheiro [push.js](https://github.com/schoolofnetcom/vue-pwa/blob/master/src/push.js) do repositório que você linkou na sua pergunta. Porém, ele só é obtido uma vez, o que significa que se ele expirar não será atualizado. (E, obviamente, o FCM não pode receber mensagens de um token que expirou)

Para atualizar este token, utilize a função [onTokenRefresh()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client?hl=pt-br#monitorar-a-atualizao-de-token):

```
messaging.onTokenRefresh(function() {
  messaging.getToken().then(function(novoToken) {
    console.log('O token mudou.');
    console.log('Enviar isso para um servidor:', novoToken);

  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Não foi possível obter o novo token ', err);
  });
});
```

Comment: Tentei usando essa função acima porém ainda não está funcionando, poderia me dar um exemplo de onde colocar ela para funcionar corretamente, pois ainda está retornando o mesmo erro...